# Why Remove data content of Openshift configmap

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

we use opebshift 4.7.
we have an issue on one of the config map .
on the openshift conteroller manager namsespace ,the configmap name is openshift-global-ca and the data of config map is removed.
here is the error log :

> mountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "proxy-ca-bundles" : configmap
> references non-existent config key: ca-bundle.crt Unable to attach or
> mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[proxy-ca-bundles], unattached
> volumes=[serving-cert proxy-ca-bundles
> openshift-controller-manager-sa-token-dfm4m config client-ca]: timed
> out waiting for the condition